# PHP and Checkboxes check ones go to table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this:

```
$query = "select * from pharmacy";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num1 = mysql_num_fields($result);

if($num>0)
{
    echo "<table border=2>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='p$i'  value='yes' unchecked /></td>";
        echo"<td>$row[0]</td>";

        echo"</tr>";
    }
```

i want to insert the checked ones in my another table in Mysql how can i insert the texts of each check boxes?

Comment: can you please clarify what you want?

Comment: I can use:if(isset($_POST['$i']) &&$_POST['$i'] == 'yes')

Comment: please provide more info, because it's very unclear in this format. Value of checkboxes? You set all fetched rows to unchecked... Do you mean you want to get all rows and insert them into another table and than update the source table with some flag that you already checked fetched? Or you just want every time to fetch results from source table and put them into another table? Be more specific please.

Comment: i want just to insert the checked ones in another table like this i have the txt:1 for check box 1 and the text 2 for check box2 when choosing ckeck box one and clicking the submit button then  the chosen one of checkboxes must be inserted in another table of mysql

Comment: Oh my. I guess you mean you want to have an html with all fetched rows + checkbox. Than you want to check X of Y results and insert only those which are checked to that another table.

Comment: What values you want to pass from source table to new one? What are the table structures? Provide more info.

Comment: yes but It is php script in the form i use php to insert my table i guess i must use if(isset($_POST['p$i']) &&$_POST['p$i'] == 'yes')  but but i don't know exactly!

Comment: i have table named:pharmecies that it's contents are drugs and when in my page a pharmacy want to register it must choose it's drugs from this database and i want to insert the chosen ones for it.

Comment: Do you want in insert the checked into a mysql table, or an html table?

Comment: it must be inserted in mysql here i put the table of html just for showing

Comment: suppose that the output like this:
| WARFARIN SODIUM TAB? 4MG                |
| WARFARIN SODIUM TAB? 5MG   when i choose the first ne it must be inserted in one of the tables of my sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off all you must change this HTML so that the checkbox is an array

```
$query = "select * from pharmacy";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num1 = mysql_num_fields($result);

if($num>0)
{
    echo "<table border=2>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='pi[$i]' /></td>";
        echo"<td>$row[0]</td>";

        echo"</tr>";
    }
```

then in the action page

```
    foreach($_POST['pi'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    if($value=="on")
    {
    //DO THE INSERT CODE HERE
// the $key is the $i counter in the HTML
// the $value is whether the user selected it no in this case its just on/off
    }
    }
```

Comment: for doing the insert code i must insert the $row[0] how can i put it here? my problem is this but you solved my array problem thank you

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['pi']  here? it is not my drugs,i think maybe i must put <input type='Checkbox' name='pi[$i]' value=$row[0]/>

Comment: MRR i found it:D thanks! i used the array $r[$i]=$row[0]; and then: if($value=="on")
    {
 $query2="insert into drug(name)values('$r[$key]')";
 echo $query2;
 $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
 
  }

Comment: There is no good reason to check `if ($value=='on')`.  If a box isn't checked, it won't be in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using POST/GET arrays like so:

```
<input type='Checkbox' name='p[]'  value='$i' unchecked />
```

Upon submitting the form you will end up with an array of  values in the `p` variable of the request parameters (POST/GET).

From here on it is quite easy to select those IDs from the original table and inserting the data into the new one.

It would look something like so:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (firsT_column, second_column, third_column)
SELECT firsT_column, second_column, third_column
FROM `old_table`
WHERE id IN (<IDS>)
```

Naturally the `<IDS>` tag should be replace by an imploded string of the `p` array from before.

Comment: <input type='Checkbox' name='p[]'  value='$i' unchecked /> You mean what from tag? i have just one column and it is my $row[0] from another table how can i insert $row[0] ?

Comment: @Negin : the value of the checkbox should be the id of the row. the name of the checkboxes should remain like i posted. this will cause all the checked values to fill the array named `p`

Answer (score 0):

I think your entire approach is wrong. Best will be to use the pharmacy primary key and insert it into your other table. I presume in that other table you save your user's ID and all drugs related to him.

Here the full example of my suggest:

**list_drugs.php**

```
$query = "select * from pharmacy";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num>0) {
    echo '<table border="2">';
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="drugid_'.$row["PRIMARY_KEY_ID"].'" value="1" unchecked /></td>';
        echo '<td>$row[0]</td>';

        echo'</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

**do_update.php**

```
<?php
foreach($_POST AS $k=>$x) {
    if(!preg_match("/[^drugid_*]/i", $k)) {
            if($x=="1") {
                $getOnlyTheDrugID=str_replace('drugid_','',$k);
                mysql_query('INSERT INTO otherTable SET columnName='.($drugid_+0).'');
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: because that's my execution code. if you don't want to split it to two scripts, just move the content (on top) from do_update.php to list_drug.php. You need a form and submit button too, which I presume you have somewhere in your code.

Comment: RRStoyanov, I know submits and etc i don't know the func preg_match how it works?

Comment: see that I named all your inputs `drugid_'.$row["PRIMARY_KEY_ID"].'`. when you submit, you don't want to get the info from other inputs, so with preg_match we get only the checked ones.

Comment: thank you RRStoyanov Idea of array worked for me and now I know the solution

Answer (score -4):

You need to give all of your checkboxes the same name. Something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="drugs[]" value="name of drug" />
```

Then in your script that process the script

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['drugs']);$i++) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (ID, Drugname) VALUES ('', '$_POST['drugs'][$i]')";
}
```

You should know how to send that query off each time

Comment: PHP kills a kitty every time when you call `count` inside a loop. `count` is called with every incrementing. And the example is not correct, because he wanted the checked.

Comment: i think after the for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['drugs']);$i++) I must write if(isset($_POST['drugs']) &&$_POST['drugs'] == 'yes')
  am i right?

Comment: @Negin: Semi.  You'll need to check whether the array exists (as it'll only exist if at least one box is checked), but you'll want to check that outside the `foreach`.  And only the checked boxes will be included in the array, so as long as you stay within the bounds of the array, every element should have a value.  Besides, in this solution, each box will have a different value, so you can't be guaranteed it'll be "yes".

Comment: @RRStoyanov That kind of micro-optimization isn't important in 99.999% of web development, and it's certainly not relevant here.

Comment: @RRStoyanov. The example is correct as only the checked checkboxes will be passed through to the script. If it's not checked, the values don't go through.

Comment: If people downvote my answer, they need to explain here why. There is nothing wrong with my answer. It does exactly what he wants. I use it all the time and it works. Though sometime I do put the count($_POST) outside the for loop, but generally it's not really a problem as it's not a highly intensive process.